# SUM week with Doctrine

Tags: php, datetime, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

March 2012:

```
9   27  28  29  1   2   3   4
10  5   6   7   8   9   10  11
11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18
12  19  20  21  22  23  24  25
13  26  27  28  29  30  31
```

First column this is number week of year - in php **date("W")**; 
I have in database MySQL:

```
id | count | date
1  | 2     | 2012-02-28 11:11:11 // 9 week
2  | 4     | 2012-02-29 11:11:11 // 9 week
3  | 5     | 2012-03-01 11:11:11 // 9 week
4  | 2     | 2012-03-03 11:11:11 // 9 week
5  | 5     | 2012-03-05 11:11:11 // 10 week
6  | 3     | 2012-03-07 11:11:11 // 10 week
7  | 6     | 2012-03-08 11:11:11 // 10 week
8  | 2     | 2012-03-12 11:11:11 // 11 week
9  | 6     | 2012-03-13 11:11:11 // 11 week
10 | 5     | 2012-03-16 11:11:11 // 11 week
11 | 1     | 2012-03-16 11:11:11 // 11 week
12 | 9     | 2012-03-16 11:11:11 // 11 week
```

How can i SUM with Symfony 1.4 and Doctrine 1.2 for all week?

In this example should show me:

```
week | count
9    | 13
10   | 14
11   | 23
```

How should look query with Doctrine?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to that http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9701b/6, I will perfom this query:

```
$query = Doctrine_Query::create()
   ->select("sum(s.count), date_format(s.date, '%v') as date_formatted")
   ->from('SomeTable s')
   ->groupBy('date_formatted');
```

I used `as date_formatted` in the select clause because Doctrine doesn't understand the `date_format` in the `groupBy` method.

Answer (score 2):

You just specify the sum in your select part of the DQL:

```
$query = Doctrine_Query::create()
   ->select('sum(amount)')
   ->from('some_table');
```